# POST request with ReactJS fails with preflight OPTION status code = 404 with YII2 REST API

Tags: reactjs, yii2

my frontend and backend is running on a nginx server which i have configure for proxy_pass, GET method is working fine but POST method was rejected because preflight request failed and preflight options came back with 404 error. How can I solve this problem to make sure preflight option return appropriate code.  Below is my REST config .

```
 ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'pluralize'=>false,
                'controller' => ['v1/auth'],
                'extraPatterns'=>[
                    'GET index'=>'index',
                    'POST login'=>'login',                    
                ],
              
            ],
```

A request to /v1/auth/login first send a preflight OPTIONS request which throw back 404. I added OPTIONS in my congif as below but didn't seems to solve the problem either

```
          ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                    'pluralize'=>false,
                    'controller' => ['v1/auth'],
                    'extraPatterns'=>[
                        'GET index'=>'index',
                        'POST login'=>'login', 
                        'OPTIONS '=>'options',
                    ],
                  
                ],
```

Answer (score 0):

When the browser is going to send POST request it first sends a preflight request to check if it's OK to send the POST request itself.
That is done by sending `OPTIONS` request to same url where the `POST` request is going to be send.

From your route rules the URL for login request is something like
`//your-domain.example/v1/auth/login`.
You have configured rule for `POST` request to this url, but there is no rule for `OPTIONS` request.
If you add pattern like this `'OPTIONS '=>'options',` it only defines routing for `OPTIONS` request to route `//your-domain.example/v1/auth`.

To define routing for `OPTIONS` requests for same url as the login `POST` requests are using you have to add pattern `'OPTIONS login' => 'options'`.
So the rule definition should look like:

```php
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
    'pluralize'=>false,
    'controller' => ['v1/auth'],
    'extraPatterns' => [
        'GET index' => 'index',
        'POST login' => 'login',
        'OPTIONS login' => 'options',
    ],
],
```